# How do I download a large (70+) number of password(?) protected files from a website using ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, downloads, wget, download-manager

I'm a first-year uni student and I need to download a relatively large number of files, in the form of URLs, that I have the permission for. I just don't know how to do that using Ubuntu on Windows. I can download individual files using this:

```
wget -nc --content-disposition --header="API-Key: INSERT_API_KEY" "INSERT_URL"
```

and I have researched and found that I could use:

```
wget -i url.txt
```

to download a large number of files since I have all the URLs in a txt file. I just don't know how to give permissions while going through every URL. If I just run the second command I get 403 errors. Could I get any help?

Comment: Did you try to combine the two command you provided?

Comment: This is why your instructor provides their contact information and office hours upon the syllabus. You are paying them for learning support like this.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes I did try that after I posted this. I'm new to ubuntu and I didn't know that I could combine things like that. It did work! I ran:

wget -nc --content-disposition --header="API-Key: INSERT_API_KEY" -i url.txt